# Allowed 2-qubit gates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, reversibility, two-level-system

I was working on some Quantum Information problems regarding allowed 2-qubit gates and got stuck. These are the proposed transformations:

1. $|A\rangle |B\rangle \rightarrow |B\rangle|\overline A\rangle $
2. $|A\rangle |B\rangle \rightarrow |\overline A\rangle| A\rangle $
3. $|A\rangle |B\rangle \rightarrow |A\oplus B\rangle| A\rangle $
4. $|A\rangle |B\rangle \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|A\rangle|B\rangle +  |\overline A\rangle|\overline B\rangle) $
5. $|A\rangle |B\rangle \rightarrow (-1)^{A+B}|A\rangle|B\rangle $

So I think:

1. Possible as unitary is reversible (we preserve $A$ and $B$ at the output)
2. Not possible as we lose information about $B$ and hence cannot recover that state (i.e. the gate would be irreversible)
3. Possible as we know how XOR ($\oplus$) operates and hence can figure $B$ out from $A \oplus B$.
4. **Here I get stuck**. It seems that we preserve the $A$ and $B$ states but can we revert the output of the gate?
5. I think possible, as we can simply remove the sign at the front and get the original input states.

Is there anything else besides reversibility I should keep in mind when it comes to validation of unitary operations?

Comment: Please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: what is $|\bar{A}\rangle$?

Comment: @glS It's NOT operation, so that $|\overline 0\rangle =  |1\rangle$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to not solve the homework but rather give insights into the right thinking direction:

I think case 4 which right now puzzles you is closely related to the [Hadamard quantum gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_transform#Quantum_computing_applications). The link to the wikipedia definition contains an expression of the Hadamard gate from which one could derive the one you need to show that indeed this is a unitary transformation.

However, considering the "*we can simply remove the sign at the front*" you mention concerning case 5, you may need to rethink how you are understanding reversibility. For the transformation to be reversible (which I agree it is), you need to *remove the sign* at the front also reversibly, i.e. not deleting any information.

Comment: It was simpler than I thought. I simply calculated the truth tables for every operation in $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ basis and tested whether the operator was unitary. In the end, I figured that only 2 and 4 were not valid gates.