# Hadamard gate over 2 qubits

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, tensor-calculus, quantum-states

Let H be the Hadamard gate:

$$(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})\begin{pmatrix}\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1  \end{array}\end{pmatrix}$$

I would like to write down the matrix associated to the gate H ⊗ H on two-qubits, so I have read its definition and found answers like these:

[How to apply a Hadamard gate?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/55696/how-to-apply-a-hadamard-gate)

[Allowed 2-qubit gates](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/399584/allowed-2-qubit-gates)

But I still do not get it, as I see some new definitions there. Is it not as simple as doing the tensor product? Like:

$$(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})\begin{pmatrix}\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1  \end{array}\end{pmatrix}  ⊗ (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})\begin{pmatrix}\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1  \end{array}\end{pmatrix}$$

And now, that door can be applied to a two-qubit system, with cases like $H|00\rangle $

Could someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate this product you can use the general rule for the tensor product (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_product_of_linear_maps)). The tensor product of two $2\times2$ matrices
$$
A =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{matrix}\right) \; , \qquad 
B =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
b_{11} & b_{12} \\
b_{21} & b_{22}
\end{matrix}\right) 
$$
is the $4\times4$ matrix
\begin{align}
A \otimes B &=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
a_{11} \left(
\begin{matrix}
b_{11} & b_{12} \\
b_{21} & b_{22}
\end{matrix}\right) & a_{12}\left(
\begin{matrix}
b_{11} & b_{12} \\
b_{21} & b_{22}
\end{matrix}\right) \\
a_{21}\left(
\begin{matrix}
b_{11} & b_{12} \\
b_{21} & b_{22}
\end{matrix}\right) & a_{22}\left(
\begin{matrix}
b_{11} & b_{12} \\
b_{21} & b_{22}
\end{matrix}\right)
\end{matrix}\right)  \\[8pt]
&=\left(
\begin{matrix}
a_{11}b_{11} & a_{11}b_{12} &  a_{12}b_{11} &  a_{12}b_{12} \\
a_{11}b_{21} & a_{11}b_{22} &  a_{12}b_{21} &  a_{12}b_{22} \\
a_{21}b_{11} & a_{21}b_{12} &a_{22} b_{11} &a_{22} b_{12} \\
a_{21}b_{21} &a_{21}b_{22} &a_{22} b_{21} &a_{22} b_{22} \\
\end{matrix}\right) 
\end{align}
for the case of $H\otimes H$ you should calculate explicitly these $16$ products.

---

#### Interpretation

In a one-qubit state, the action of the Hadamard gate sends $|0\rangle$ to $|+\rangle$. That is,
$$ H \left(
\begin{matrix}
1\\
0
\end{matrix}\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \left(
\begin{matrix}
1\\
1
\end{matrix}\right) \, . $$
The tensor product $H\otimes H$ is constructed so that it sends $|00\rangle$ to $|++\rangle$ (as well as for the other basis vectors). That is,
$$ H \otimes H \left(
\begin{matrix}
1\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{matrix}\right) = \frac{1}{2}  \left(
\begin{matrix}
1\\
1\\
1\\
1
\end{matrix}\right) \, . $$
With the matrix that you calculated previously for $H\otimes H$, you should be able to verify this equation.

---

If you are new to quantum mechanics and quantum information the basic reference "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information" from Nielsen and Chuang, chapters 01 and 02 are essentials.

Comment: Exactly! I have done it and proved it. I will post a comment doing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would add that when you apply a single qubit gate on each of $n$ qubits, the resulting gate is described by matrix
$$
U_1 \otimes U_2 \otimes \dots \otimes U_n,
$$
where $U_i$ is a gate applied on $i$th qubit.

The same is true for quantum states, if your $i$th qubit is in state $|\psi_i\rangle$ then **under assumption there is no entanglement among the qubits**, the "total" state of the qubits is
$$
|\psi_1\rangle \otimes |\psi_2\rangle  \otimes \dots \otimes |\psi_n\rangle.
$$

Comment: Also! I will add it on my response here.